# Whole Disk Encryption and power failures

Tags: hard-drive, encryption, truecrypt, veracrypt

I believe encryption softwares like TrueCrypt and VeraCrypt support whole disk encryption.

Now lets say I open my computer give my decryption password and successfully boot and am using my computer. Lets say the power suddenly goes off, and the computer shuts off. What happens then ?

Correct me if I am wrong, the contents on my hard disk are still in the decrypted format right ?

Or lets say while encrypting the computer crashes due to a power failure or a hardware failure, what happens then ?

Comment: "What happens then ?" - Your computer is turned off.  When the power is restored, the computer would have to be turned back on, and you would have to provide the passphrase in order to boot your system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the disk contents remain encrypted even while in use – the OS decrypts sectors *in memory*. (Just like in the 2nd question, you noted that encrypting the disk takes a long time. If the OS had to fully decrypt it on each boot, that would also take just as long – not to mention being useless.)

Most full-disk-encryption software keeps track of the current encryption progress (inside the encrypted volume header). After a power outage, there shouldn't be data loss since TrueCrypt can just resume from that point – or at least no more than a few sectors at the boundary.

Comment: Here is my confusion. Is the OS performing the decryption or TrueCrypt ? Lets say after logging into my machine I want to watch a movie that is say 2 GB in size, so will TrueCrypt proceed to decrypt that sector if it is not decrypted ? Also if TrueCrypt is doing the decryption doesn't that mean the OS will run on top of TrueCrypt ? This is wear I am going of the deep end. Could you explain it in more detail please.

Comment: The initial boot stages might run "on top", but afterwards the OS just inserts TrueCrypt's disk driver between the real disk driver and the filesystem. Sectors are usually 4 kB or 512 b in size; TrueCrypt decrypts each sector the moment the OS requests it. (The video player doesn't read the whole 2 GB at once, either. – it streams data as necessary.)

Comment: So the decryption key stays in memory right? So can't someone dump the contents of the RAM and get the key ?

Comment: They could, [if they do it fast enough.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_boot_attack)